# How to generate Doctrine entities From Database and Use PSR-4 Autoloading?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, psr-4

Using Doctrine `2.5` with PSR-4 autoloading and converting an already designed database schema to entity classes (annotations). The problem is getting the exported files in the correct directory structure.

*composer.json*

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5"
    }
}
```

*orm:convert-mapping*

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping \
    --namespace='Application\Entity\' \
    --force \
    --from-database  \
    annotation \
    src/
```

Running this command will add an `Application` directory in `src/`.
The generated class file has the correct namespace but in the wrong directory for PSR-4 standard.

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;


}
```

Is there a way to solve this without a secondary command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any option from `doctrine cli` for this needed. I just see the solution to modify the directory structure from your Application module. Here I modify the `composer.json`

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\": "src/Application/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5"
    }
}
```

All `Application` module source code will be put on `src/Application` not `src/` anymore. So, when `doctrine cli` create directory `Application/Entity` in `src`, it will match with yor `psr-4` Autoloader.